# Make sslh or nginx listen to serial port, to get VPN or HTTP(S) or SSH over serial port (real, emulated and/or virtual)

Tags: ssh, nginx, serial-port, serial-console, socat

I would like to make more services than [serial-console](/questions/tagged/serial-console)-login available via [serial-port](/questions/tagged/serial-port). In essence, I want to make a traditionally network-listening service (with strong encryption/authentication) of machine **A** available via Serial. My first GoTo was [`sslh`](https://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh/README.html), since it's made for multiplexing a bunch of services over one port. My second GoTo, was `[nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx).

This is mostly for situations where you are

- debugging/configuring the main networking connection of a Hypervisor or VM **A** while having an independent connection to a machine **B**, that is connected via (real or virtual) Serial[[-over-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_over_LAN) via [IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface#RMCP)] to **A**.
- wanting to ensure comfort/security of transmission where my only access is via console server in un-trusted networks/infrastructure. (And I don't want to mess around with [kermit](/questions/tagged/kermit) and `lrzsz` anymore.)

I'm aware of the following workarounds/semi-solutions, and listing them to preempt suggestions:

- Run [pppd](/questions/tagged/pppd) on [both ends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218780/pppd-issue-over-serial-cable): Works, yes, but then I have to take care of additional routing, naming, address allocation/creation etc. This is my currently used option. But I want to avoid setting up all this additional networking.
- Run [slirp](/questions/tagged/slirp) [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slirp), like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322258/127903): Would work similar to [ppp](/questions/tagged/ppp), but older.

Running PPPd/slirp also requires I run either VPN, SSH, and/or HTTPS over this link anyway. (I'm aware of [encryption possibilities for PPP](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/mppe.htm), but they're weak or [EAP-TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2716), but I want to avoid managing even more sets of credentials)

The "services" I mainly want to use over this "serial connection" are interactive shells, file-transfers, and HTTP(s) to VMs/containers/etc. "on or behind" host **A**.

So, I attempted to get [sslh](/questions/tagged/sslh) to "listen on serial" using the "foreground mode"`-f`, that [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) also uses, and the "inetd"`-i` option; various version of this:

```
socat -d -d file:/dev/ttyS0,b115200,raw,ignoreeof,echo=0 SYSTEM:'sslh -i --ssh 127.0.0.1:22 --http 127.0.0.1:80'
```

But, in this incantation, [sslh](/questions/tagged/sslh) complains about the format of the options, even though `sslh` happily runs with them when "--listen"ing on `127.0.0.1:2222`, so then I tried various versions of:

```
socat -d -d file:/dev/ttyS0,b115200,raw,ignoreeof,echo=0 tcp:127.0.0.1:2222
```

Now `socat` runs, so I unsuccessfully tried to connect from the other side with variations of:

```
ssh foo -o "Proxycommand=socat -d -d -d - /dev/ttyUSB0,b115200,ignoreeof,raw,echo=0"
```

as suggested [here in a not-quite-working attempt](https://serverfault.com/a/911077/303997) or like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218413/127903):

```
ssh -v foo -o "ProxyCommand bash -c 'exec 3<>/dev/ttyUSB0; cat <&3 & cat >&3'"
```

I tried ["Serial to SSH" as suggested in this unconfirmed answer](https://serverfault.com/a/911077/303997) on a [similar in-active question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/892892/how-to-use-ssh-over-serial-without-using-pppd-or-how-to-transfer-tcp-over-ser). The answer there is "*SHOULD* work", but doesn't for me.

I mention [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) in the title, because I already have a functioning service-multiplexing of nginx([SSL[-ALPN]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation)/HTTPS/SSLH(SSH,OpenVPN,HTTP)) similar to [this](https://superuser.com/a/1343424/481365)&[this](https://superuser.com/a/1328474/481365) working, that happily also [listens on `unix:`-sockets](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html#listen), but that I can't make use a serial port using the same syntax. I also tried "bridging" `/dev/ttySX` to `UNIX-CONNECT:/run/nginx-XYZ.sock` with `socat`.

I *think*, my problem, is that `socat` opens both sides directly at the start, instead of waiting for packets to arrive from the left side(= the SSH-client) first, and then only to trigger opening the second side of the command (to the SSH server).

**So, long story short: How can I get either [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh),[sslh](/questions/tagged/sslh),or [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) to listen on a serial port, with or without helper programs like [socat](/questions/tagged/socat)?** Is there a generic solution to this?

Alternatively: I'd also be happy about examples for `.`[ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh)[`/config`](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/openssh-client/ssh_config.5.en.html)/[systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd)-integrated tooling for both sides of the serial that makes `pppd` with autogenerated (IPv6?) addresses transparent and automatic.

Note: Onboard serial ports usually offer 1.5MBits/s, and most USB serial port adapters support 3MB/s, so fast enough for SSH, and "rsync-over-ssh a backup of `/etc`". Plus there is compression.

Note2: I'm aware, I'll only get one concurrent connection over serial, and I'll maybe need to wait for a timeout to use the port again, but 1 SSH/TCP-OpenVPN will do to mux anything I need over that one connection.